# How to create hex from file buffer in Node

Tags: node.js, cryptography

Using Typescript / Node / Crypto to create a hash.

`const fileBuffer = readFileSync(filePath);`

```
const hashedFileName = crypto
      .createHash("md5")
      .update(fileBuffer)
      .digest("hex");
```

But getting a ...

```
Argument of type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BinaryLike'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is missing the following properties from type 'Float64Array': BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, buffer, byteOffset, copyWithin, and 23 more.
```

Is there a way to make this work? What is BinaryLike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ArrayBuffer` is not a valid argument for `.update` you have to convert it to a `Buffer` or `Uint8Array`

```
const hashedFileName = crypto
      .createHash("md5")
      .update(new Uint8Array(fileBuffer))
      // .update(Buffer.from(fileBuffer))
      .digest("hex");
```

Comment: In my case I had to change `Uint8Array.from` to `new Uint8Array`.

Comment: Yeah I thought I typed `Buffer.from` instead of `new Uint8Array`, updated the answer @KTibow thanks!